# Why my dropdown menu doesn't work properly?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I wonder why my dropdown menu in the navbar doesn't work properly. When I click on the portfolio button, it does not response, here is my code:

```
/*PUG*/
doctype html
html
  head 
  title Matsu
  link(rel='stylesheet' href='/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css')
  link(rel='stylesheet' href='/css/style.css')
body
  nav.navbar.navbar-expand-lg.navbar-dark.bg-dark
    a.navbar-brand(href='#') Website
    button.navbar-toggler(type='button' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#navbarNavDropdown' aria-controls='navbarNavDropdown' aria-expanded='false' aria-label='Toggle navigation')
      span.navbar-toggler-icon
  #navbarNavDropdown.collapse.navbar-collapse
    ul.navbar-nav.mr-auto.mt-2.mt-lg-0 
      li.nav-item.active 
        a.nav-link(href='/') Home 
      li.nav-item
        a.nav-link(href='/about') About
      li.nav-item.dropdown
        a#navbarDropdownMenuLink.nav-link.dropdown-toggle(href='#', role='button', data-toggle='dropdown', aria-haspopup='true', aria-expanded='false')
          | Portfolio
        .dropdown-menu(aria-labelledby='navbarDropdownMenuLink')
          a.dropdown-item(href='/1') 1
          a.dropdown-item(href='/2') 2
          a.dropdown-item(href='/3') 3
          a.dropdown-item(href='/4') 4
block content
footer
  p Copyright &copy; 2020

script(src='/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js')  
script(src='/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js')
script(src='/js/main.js')
```

I am not sure if I should provide other code or not. I've looked up bootstrap navbar explanation and transfer the html code into pug step by step, but I still cannot solve this pug, thank you.

[Navbar Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGNIG.jpg)
[Project Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x25IN.jpg)

Comment: Please define "doesn't work properly"

Comment: "doesn't work properly" means that the "portfolio" does not show the dropdown list 1,2,3,4. I can only click it like a button, but I would like to click the list(meny) 1, 2, 3, 4 link, thank you.

Comment: So the list does not open on click? Have you checked the bootstrap/jquery code is loaded properly?

Comment: Oh!! Thank you, the problem is solved! I didn't find that my bootstrap/jquery is noy loaded properly, I thought it would be loaded when I install bootstrap,but it didn't. I should have checked this.